# Does notetaking that does not involve writting by hand help remeber information?

Tags: psychology, learning, school

I've often heard that taking notes helps remember information, even if you don't read it again. Here's [an article](http://dyslexia.yale.edu/Technology.html) that sites studies that supports this. For this to happen must the note taking be done by hand or can it be typed on a computer? For people familiar with the Android app Swype, does taking notes with it help remember information?

I'm curious what methods of note taking help people remember because dyslexic people may have difficulty writing by hand.

Comment: Do you have a notable claim you'd like us to examine? Unless someone has claimed that it must be done by hand, there's nothing here for us to examine...

Comment: That's my question: has anyone claimed it must be done by hand?

Comment: Then your question is off-topic here. This site is for examining notable claims.

Comment: [Why You Learn More Effectively by Writing Than Typing](http://lifehacker.com/5738093/why-you-learn-more-effectively-by-writing-than-typing) is such a claim; I don't know whether the claim is true, nor how it may be relevant to dyslexic people. Also [Writing by hand better for learning, study shows](http://news.medill.northwestern.edu/chicago/news.aspx?id=177291) and maybe others.

Comment: @ChrisW: Thanks for finding those. I considered taking one of those claims and editing it into the question, but I figure the OP isn't challenging those, and would probably accept them as an answer, because this isn't a Skeptics.SE question, but a general research question. Closing.

Comment: I can't imagine using something like Swype (or any touch screen keyboard) to take notes since I find myself constantly looking down at the screen to be sure that I typed what I think I typed. When on a regular keyboard, I never have to look at the keys and can type reflexively without thinking about it. Do some people get that good with touchscreens? Based on the SMS's I receive from friends, my friends can't type accurately on a touch screen either.